# In visual studio, how can I write a macro that will insert the date into a comment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, macros, comments, visual-studio-macros

My question is as exact as it is. I am wondering if it would be possible to insert the date or the date and time into a comment without having to manually write it out. But what I would really like to know is, is there a way to do this and will I have to implement something with visual studio to do this for me and if so, how can I do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)
Also, I am coding in C-Sharp and am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: What programming language would you be using?

Comment: I am currently writing in C-Sharp.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2010 you write macros in Visual Basic and add them to the Macro Explorer.  Then  call the macros while working in your C# code editor.  I bind my favorite macros to key combinations, so I can quickly run them when needed.

If you are new to macros and the Visual Studio Macro editor check out this link.
[MSDN docs for Macros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4c73967%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Here is the code to add a comment and date to your C# code.

```
 Public Sub AddCommentWithDate()
    Dim doc As Document = DTE.ActiveDocument
    ' only modify the doc, if it is a text document in VS
    Dim textDoc As TextDocument = _
       CType(doc.Object("TextDocument"), TextDocument)

    ' verify that the code editor is C#
    If doc.ProjectItem.ContainingProject.Kind = _
       VSLangProj.PrjKind.prjKindCSharpProject Then
        textDoc.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint()
        textDoc.Selection.Insert("// A comment " & Date.Now)
    End If
End Sub
```

Here's the results in a C# file.

```
// A comment 3/18/2013 2:13:38 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either write a macro in Visual Studio or use some external program (such as [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)) to *type* the text for you.

Answer (score -1):

When someone posts a comment and you process the form data on your serverside,
maybe you would add a hard return (
 or  chr(13)) and then add the date BEFORE persisting the comments to a database or xml file.

so you would end up with something like....

```
Comments == Comments + Strings.Chr(13) + System.DateTime.Today
```

or

```
Comments == Comments + ("<br />") + System.DateTime.Today
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a Visual Studio macro to insert the date into their C# source code when they add a comment.